# Weird java for-each behavior when swapping variables

Tags: java

With the follow code, I expect four elements, but get only three.  Clearly I'm doing something crazy silly.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

import java.util.Set;

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] myStrings = new String[] { "a", "b" };

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String x : myStrings) {
            for (String y : myStrings) {
                String temp = x;
                x = y;
                y = temp;

                set.add(x + y);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

result:

```
[ba, aa, ab]
```

Comment: (1) Where's bb?  (2) This is just a simple example testing for-each iteration.

Comment: wrong! The variables x and y are getting munged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sets don't allow duplicates, and you're adding 'ba' twice.  Your loop control if confusing, but here's the simplified trace, with rvalues expanded.

```
x = "a"

y = "a"
temp = "a"
x = "a"
y = "a"
add("aa")

y = "b"
temp = "a"
x = "b"
y = "a"
add("ba")

x = "b"

y = "a"
temp = "b"
x = "a"
y = "b"
add("ab")

y = "b"
temp = "a"
x = "b"
y = "a"
add("ba")
```

Comment: Who can say, what with x and y being swapped back and forth.

Comment: @Laurence, yeah, I realized that as I did my trace.

Comment: @Jason the code may be confusing, but it's still deterministic.

Comment: @Laurence, I'm pretty sure he was kidding.

Comment: @Matthew Who can say, what with all the crazy stuff people say on the Internets.

Comment: yup, I was just being sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the variable of the outer loop each time you run through the inner loop. So `x` can become corrupted.

In particular the penultimate execution of the body assigns `'a'` to `x`. Next time round the loop we miss out on `"bb"`, instead getting a duplicat `"ab"`.

Using `final` is quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

Playing with loop variables is the issue.

Do this:

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String x : myStrings) {
        for (String y : myStrings) {
            String temp = x;
            x = y;
            y = temp;
            System.out.println(x+y);
            set.add(x + y);
        }
    }
```

You will see you are adding ab twice, which in a Set means overwriting. Then change the loop to use something other than loop variables like:

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String a : myStrings) {
        for (String b : myStrings) {
            String x = a;
            String y = b;
            String temp = x;
            x = y;
            y = temp;
            System.out.println(x+y);
            set.add(x + y);
        }
    }
```

And you will get all 4 things you want. I have to do some more reading about how traversing an array in the way you have done works, but that is clearly the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the outer loop variable, so the output is unexpectedly missing "bb".

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String x : myStrings) {
    for (String y : myStrings) {
        String temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;

        set.add(x + y);
    }
}
```

Why are you assigning things to `x` and `y` when they are both  for loop variables? If you wish to loop through `x` and `y` independently, get rid of those 3 lines to swap x and y. You are modifying the variables in a way that is probably different than you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's because you're putting the resulting strings into a hash set, which doesn't preserve order. Try with a linked hash set.

Comment: Whether order is preserved or not wouldn't affect how many elements you end up with in the collection.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is simple -- where is "bb" in the output.  It should generate 4 strings.